# Why the first model can't receive data in a singleton generator that had emit data?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I had a `Generate` instance that only create one and initialize once.it emit data while it running.Then I had new two `Model` that use the same `Generate` instance that receive data from `Generate` instance.After I new two view to present it,but the first `Model` can't receive data from `Generate` instance,it puzzle me why the first model can't receive data???

**The Code:**

```py
import random
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

randId = lambda: random.choice([1, 2])
randChr = lambda: chr(random.randint(0, 0xff))

class Generate(QThread):
    _instance = None
    _isHadInit = False
    sigData = pyqtSignal(int, str)

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super().__new__(cls)

        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        if self._isHadInit: return
        self._isHadInit = True
        self.start()

    @classmethod
    def instance(cls):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = Generate()

        return cls._instance

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.sleep(1)
            self.sigData.emit(randId(), randChr())

class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, id):
        super().__init__()
        self._list = []
        self._id = id
        self.G = Generate()
        self.G.sigData.connect(self.onReceiveData)

    def onReceiveData(self, id, data):
        print("gen", id, data)
        if id == self._id:
            self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
            self._list.append(data)
            self.layoutChanged.emit()

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self._list)

    def columnCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        return 1

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role):
        if index.isValid() and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(self._list[index.row()])

        return None

class View(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        m1 = Model(1)
        m2 = Model(2)

        v1 = QListView()
        v1.setModel(m1)

        v2 = QListView()
        v2.setModel(m2)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(v1)
        layout.addWidget(v2)

        self.setLayout(layout)

app = QApplication([])
v = View()
v.show()
app.exec()
```

**The Effect:**
[image: The View]

**The Terminal:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies at:

```py
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        if self._isHadInit: return
        self._isHadInit = True
        self.start()
```

The `super().__init__()` is the step that binds the signal, so, here the shared `sigData` signal gets "rebound" in `Model(2)` when it calls init on the `Generate`  instance a second time.
This apparently disconnects all previous connected slots on this signal, and thus `Model(1)` will not be receive updates.

Restructuring the code as

```py
        g = Generate()
        m1 = Model(1, g)
        m2 = Model(2, g)
```

solves this without needing to resort to the global-instance tricks you are doing with `Generate`.

Alternatively

```py
    def __init__(self):
        if self._isHadInit: return
        super().__init__()
        self._isHadInit = True
        self.start()
```

should avoid re-init'ing the signal.

Comment: Yes for your two solutions,I had solved it before but now I KNOW  the reason that you have telled me.